# How to sort/order get_next_post_link in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, posts

I'm using `get_next_post_link` for next and previous posts but I don't understand the order.
I would like to sort posts by acf value (a number) and order by ascending.

My code:

```php
<?php
    if ( get_next_post_link() ) {
        next_post_link();
     }
?>
```

My acf field: 'position' and its unique value so I can sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Try somethink like this

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters

https://themeisle.com/blog/re-order-wordpress-blog-posts/

```php
$wp_query = WP_Query('orderby' => 'title', 'order'   => 'DESC');

      while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {
           $wp_query->the_post();
          
          
           get_next_post_link(); //this should work

           //if not here is alternative
           $next_post = get_next_post(); // or $wp_query->next_post();
           echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID );
       
}
```

If you have any other logic to get the next post you will need to use wp_query to fetch it and then you can use get_permalink($id)

Or you can overwrite the default action which fetches posts in WordPress.

```php
// # template-functions.php

function order_posts_by_title( $query ) { 

   if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) { 

     $query-set( 'orderby', 'title' ); 

     $query-set( 'order', 'ASC' ); 

   } 

} 

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'order_posts_by_title' );
// now the get_posts(); and get_next_post(), get_next_post_link() will be ordered by custom query
```

Comment: I have an error 500 while saving code. I put the first one between <?php //$wp_query = WP_...//  ?>